# Plane symmetries of chessboard

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this in an abstract algebra book. Consider a chessboard. It has four plane symmetries : $e,r,q_1,q_2$ where $e$ is the identity, $r$ is the rotation by $\pi$ through the centre, $q_1,q_2$ are reflections in its two diagonals. These form a group under composition.

What I'm confused about is - why do we say $e \cdot r = r$ ? Can I not say $e \cdot r = e$ since chessboard rotated $\pi$ degrees is the same as the original?

What I am confusing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We sat $e\cdot r=r$ because the effect of doing $e\cdot r$ is the same as doing $r$ -  the chessboard is still rotated through $\pi$ and not in its original position (label the vertices, and check). The final positions of the chessboard all look the same, but the group distinguishes between them. Labelling the vertices is (in this case) enough to identify the group elements.

Comment: Oh I have been so stupid. Cheers!